# Creating a complex variable content by hand

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, variable-substitution

I am creating a shell script dynamically and sending it to a remote server for execution. All is working except when I try to inject a variable with content coming from a file with multiple lines, single and double quotes, and other special characters -- the system tries to execute the file.

Example:

```
my_script=$(cat some script.sh)

cont=$(cat some_template_with_special_chars.sh)
var='the_var_name_to_inject'
kv="$var=$file_contents"

script_to_send=$kv$my_script

sh -t -t -i key usr@ip "$script_to_send"
```

Now if the contents of some_template_with_special_chars.sh are simple text it works, if it has multiple lines and special chars it doesn't. Another issue is it's losing the spaces despite using double quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use "printf" to escape strings

If I understand this correctly, you're creating a variable assignment statement which will be concatenated with a script file, and everything will be executed in a shell.

In this case, I suggest something along the lines of:

```
#!/bin/bash

my_script=$(<somescript.sh)

cont=$(<file)
var='xx'

# This will escape the string in $cont, and store it in $kv
printf -v kv "$var=%q" "$cont"

script_to_send="$kv
$my_script"

# sh -c used for testing here
sh -c "$script_to_send"
```

#### Example:

Assume that `somescript.sh` is

```
echo "This is the value of xx:"
echo "$xx"
echo 'Script terminated'
```

and `file` contains

```
aa
bb"
'cc
dd
```

#### Output:

```
This is the value of xx:
aa
bb"
'cc
dd
Script terminated
```

Comment: It will contain all sort of special chars. Double and single quotes and almost all special chars.

Comment: My God. I spent +6 hours yesterday trying to figure this out. Thank you so much.